# Maven not recognizing added packages

Tags: java, maven, package, dependencies

I am developing a project with Maven for the first time. I have an external package that I have converted into a .jar file and installed into maven in order to use its classes. However, even tho the package is already in the .m2 folder maven still says that it cannot find the package(util):

```
[ERROR]/home/luis/Desktop/git/sifu/Challenges/Java/java_0002_SN/stringNorm/src/main/java/stringNorm/MyDetector.java:[14,27] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class report
  location: class stringNorm.MyDetector
[ERROR]/home/luis/Desktop/git/sifu/Challenges/Java/java_0002_SN/stringNorm/src/main/java/stringNorm/MyDetector.java:[9,1] package util does not exist
[ERROR]/home/luis/Desktop/git/sifu/Challenges/Java/java_0002_SN/stringNorm/src/main/java/stringNorm/MyDetector.java:[19,23] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class report
  location: class stringNorm.MyDetector
```

I have already tried to add this new dependency(util) to the pom file and so far it looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.sifu</groupId>
  <artifactId>stringNorm</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spotBugsVersion>4.0.0</spotBugsVersion>
  </properties>

  <description>My SpotBugs plugin project</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
      <artifactId>spotbugs</artifactId>
      <version>${spotBugsVersion}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.13</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>util</groupId>
      <artifactId>util</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
      <artifactId>test-harness</artifactId>
      <version>${spotBugsVersion}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.19.1</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>validate-spotbugs-configuration</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>validate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <validationSets>
                <validationSet>
                  <dir>src/main/resources</dir>
                  <includes>
                    <include>findbugs.xml</include>
                  </includes>
                  <systemId>findbugsplugin.xsd</systemId>
                </validationSet>
                <validationSet>
                  <dir>src/main/resources</dir>
                  <includes>
                    <include>messages.xml</include>
                  </includes>
                  <systemId>messagecollection.xsd</systemId>
                </validationSet>
              </validationSets>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spotbugs</artifactId>
            <version>${spotBugsVersion}</version>
          </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I am using spotbugs to perform analysis on my code, as you can see from the snipet.
The class within the unit package I want to use, is the report one, my import statement looks like this `import util.*;

I installed my jar file to maven using this command: `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>`

and after doing it I added it into the pom file.

My util package is composed of 3 classes, I did `jar cfv util.jar *` inside the util folder and gave me a jar file.

Comment: Please add th messages as text not as image. Also add the relevant code

Comment: Why do you have it as system scope?

Comment: @DaveNewton I saw the 6 possible entries and looked like the best

Comment: How? "This scope is similar to provided except that you have to provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is always available and is not looked up in a repository."

Comment: so what should I use?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope

Comment: I have tried both the compile and runtime scopes and still has the same error

Comment: Then it's impossible to know what's happening without specific details regarding your `util` artifact and how it was installed to your local Maven repository.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the jar installation process and creation